# Condition associated with closed sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis

When looking back at some notes on the topological exposition for analysis, I came across a proof of a condition that I had initially overlooked; it stated,

Any subset $K \subset X$ of a metric space $X$ is closed iff $x_j \in K, x_j \to p \in X \longrightarrow p \in K$.

The 'if' part was quite simple. However, the proof of the converse stated that, upon introducing $q \in U = X \setminus K$, and assuming that $X\setminus K$ is not open, then $B_{1/n} (q)$ is not contained within $U$ ($\forall n$). Hence $\exists x_n \in K \cap B_{1/n} (q)$, implying that $x_j \to q$, a contradiction.

For the most part, it is understandable, but the existence of a specific $x_n$ in the intersection seemed like it was stated without justification - or it might just be me missing something obvious. Could anyone please offer some clarification? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $B_{1/n}(q)$ is not contained in $X\setminus K$, there must be some element that is in $K\cap B_{1/n}(q)$. Since this is true for each $n$, we get a sequence $(x_n)_n$ satisfying $x_n\in K\cap B_{1/n}(q)$.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I was assuming that it applied to any sequence in $K$, rather than one formed by the ball. Thanks!